# Django Tastypie interaction with the API through PostMan REST client

Tags: django, json, rest

I was trying to create a Login module in tastypie Api, when testing it with Postman REST client getting error.

```
Method : POST
format : application/json
content type : json

raw data:  {
             'type': 'login',
             'username': 'username',
             'password': 'password'
            }



def login(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))

    username = data.get('username', '')
    password = data.get('password', '')

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': True
            })
        else:
            return self.create_response(request, {
                'success': False,
                'reason': 'disabled',
                }, HttpForbidden )
    else:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': False,
            'reason': 'incorrect',
            }, HttpUnauthorized )
```

### error message in Postman

> {
>       "error_message": "Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)",
>       "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 178, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args,
>   **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 379, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request,
>   **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 409, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n 
>   File
>   \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 1077, in post_list\n    deserialized = self.deserialize(request,
>   request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE',
>   'application/json'))\n\n  File
>   \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\",
>   line 328, in deserialize\n    deserialized =
>   self._meta.serializer.deserialize(data,
>   format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))\n\n  File
>   \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/serializers.py\",
>   line 157, in deserialize\n    deserialized = getattr(self, \"from_%s\"
>   % desired_format)(content)\n\n  File
>   \"/home/sayone/virtuals/pharma/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/serializers.py\",
>   line 301, in from_json\n    return simplejson.loads(content)\n\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py\", line 326, in loads\n
>   return _default_decoder.decode(s)\n\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 366, in decode\n    obj,
>   end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())\n\n  File
>   \"/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py\", line 382, in raw_decode\n
>   obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)\n\nValueError: Expecting property
>   name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)\n" }

Answer (score 2):

replace single quotes with double quotes
ex:

```
 {"type":"login","username":"username", "password":"password" }
```